# CSS new-line/line-break spacing

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Left</button>
    <button>Middle</button>
    <button>Right</button>
</div>
```

I can see spacing between buttons, which I understand is due to the CR/LF between each button markup.

Is there a way to correct this with CSS?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by CR/LF?

Comment: post some more code ..what property used for class `buttons`

Comment: CR/LF means carriage-return/line-feed, end of line characters

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/dqe3565c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are 2 ways:

**First Way:**

Set the `html` markup side by side

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Left</button><button>Middle</button><button>Right</button>
</div>
```

**Second Way**

Set `float:left` in the `buttons`

```
button{
float:left;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Always read the question carefully.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to set the html markup side by side?

Comment: I am not sure why so many down votes, this answer is actually correct in showing the two ways of solving the problem, one by altering the HTML and one by using floats to avoid the inline white-space issue.

Comment: its because people are coming here are biased.. they blindly `upvote` and `down vote` without understanding the current situation.

Comment: It should be pointed out that floating and inline-block aren't compatible. One or the other...not both.

Comment: I still stand by the html change.... you could add 20 lines of space between the buttons, they would still sit as desired.

Comment: You can see the reflection now...

Comment: @Paulie_D float is what is intended, inline-block will not solve the white-space issue that is the crux of the question.

Comment: If you remove `float:left;` technically your answer will correct.

Comment: Which is why this is a duplicate.

Comment: @KheemaPandey `Inline-block` will **not** solve this issue alone.

Comment: it will remove space if you are not giving in your HTML markup.